# Determine max # json array elements in Oracle table

Tags: json, oracle, plsql

Oracle PL/SQL version is Release 12.1.0.2.0. Need to determine the max # of elements in an array in an Oracle clob where a json value is stored in a table (thousands of rows). Looping and doing;

```
select count(0) into v_occurrences where json_exists(fieldname,'$.arrayname[i]')
```

...until I get a zero is what comes to mind but it's dead slow. Is there something better in my version of Oracle?

Comment: does   `'$.arrayname[i]'` works? shouldn't this needed to be `'$.arrayname[*]'`?

Comment: you may consider to create index on `'$.arrayname[i]'